# Git connection with remote (push, pull) hang with ntlm proxy mapping (ntlmaps or cntlm)

Tags: git, ntlm

When behind a proxy that uses ntlm, and using ntlmaps and git proxy configuration, I can't get git to push.

Example .gitconfig

```
[user]
    name = Mr X
    email = immrx@mrx.com
[core]
    autocrlf = true
[http]
    proxy = http://localhost:5865
```

ntlmaps is set to answer on port 5865 of course.

I try to push, but I don't get an HTTP 407 after CONNECT, the push just hangs there, and I get no answer. Finally, I have to kill the push

Comment: Try to explore what happens using a tool like Wireshark. I think there could be many things going on, you need to reduce the number of possibilities and find something that proofs at least what level the problem occurs at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the DNS don't get resolved. You can try with localhost, or your own machine name (maybe with the domain). For example mrxmachine or mrxmachine.mrx.com. They will all fail, but you won't get an answer because, for some reason, git can't resolve the DNS. Being explicit about the ip for localhost will do.

Try

```
[user]
    name = Mr X
    email = immrx@mrx.com
[core]
    autocrlf = true
[http]
    proxy = http://127.0.0.1:5865
```

or use your own ip (you can check it in a cmd window with ipconfig)